# HTML Unescape is not unescaping special characters

Tags: python-3.x, html-escape-characters

My program does not unescape the HTML special characters for quotes and I can't figure out why. It still displays the special characters in the Terminal.

For example: `'In the comic book &quot;Archie&quot;`

```
import requests
import html

API_URL = "https://opentdb.com/api.php"

parameters = {
    "amount": 10,
    "type": "boolean"
}

response = requests.get(API_URL, params=parameters)
data = html.unescape(response.json())
unescaped_data = data["results"]
print(f"UNESCAPED DATA: {unescaped_data}") # THIS IS NOT WORKING
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result isn't unescaped because `response.json()` returns a JSON object (i.e. a `dict`) and not a string. If you wanted to, you could unescape the response string using `html.unescape(response.text)` but this will leave you with invalid JSON, e.g.: `"question":""Windows NT" is a monolithic kernel.",` (note the additional quotes). So the escaping is there for a reason and you will have to unescape only those parts that you really need, that is, the string components of your JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed `response.json()` to `response.text` it works

`data = html.unescape(response.text)`

Comment: This will create invalid JSON however. The escaping is there to prevent that.